# Help with a proof by induction.

Tags: induction, self-learning, axioms, peano-axioms

I'm reading *On Mathematical Induction* by Leon Henkin in JSOTR. And well, in the first part of the article the author given us the necessary properties to be a Peano Model.

A model $\langle N,0,S\rangle$ where $N$ is a set, $0\in N$ and $S$ is an unary operation is a Peano Model if it is satisfies the following condition:

> (P1) $\forall x\in N \,(0\not=Sx)$
>
> (P2) $\forall x,y\in N\,(x\not=y \Rightarrow Sx\not=Sy )$
>
> (P3)  Let $G$ an arbitrary subset of $N$ such that $0\in G$ and $Sx\in G$ whenever $x\in G$. Then $G=N$.

After this, there is a paragraph where says:

(P4) If y is any element of $N$ such that $y\not=Sx$ for each $x\in N$ then $y=0$

(P5) For all $x\in N$, $x\not=Sx$.

Clearly each one P4 and P5 holds in any Peano Model, but the author in the third page says the proof o P4 only requires axiom P3 and P5 requires axiom P1 as well as axiom P3.

So I work to prove P4 and P5 only using these axioms.

> Proof of P4: Let $G$ be the set such that:
>
> $$z\in G \iff z\in N \text{ and } z=0 \text{ or } z=Sx \text{ for some } x\in N. $$
>
> Clearly $0 \in G$. We suppose that $y\in G$; we wish to show that $G$ is closed under $S$.
>
> So either $y=0$ or $y=Sx$ for some $x\in N$. If $y=0$ then it is easy to see that $Sy \in G$. On the other hand if $y = Sx$ for some $x\in N$. $Sy\in N$ and as $y\in N$ by hypothesis, it follows that $Sy\in G$. Hence $Sy\in G$ as desired.
>
> To conclude, if $y \not= Sx$ for each $x\in N$ then only $y$ must be equal to $0$.

And in the next proof is where I have troubles to close the induction because I only assume P1 and P3 and no more. I don't know how to prove it without the use of P2. Here is my approach:

> Proof of P5: Let G be the set such that:
>
> $$z\in G \iff z\in N \text{ and } z\not= Sz. $$
>
> Clearly $0\in G$ as an specific case of P1. Suppose that $y\in G$ we need to show that $Sy\in G$ as well. We see that $y\not= Sy$ (as $y\in G$) just we need to prove that $Sy \not=S(Sy)$

And here exactly is where I'm stuck if we use P2 for almost trivial reason the claim holds. But I can't see how with this restriction I can close the induction. I would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N=\{0,1,2\}$ and define $S0=1,\ S1=S2=2.$ Then axioms $P_1$ and $P_3$ hold, but the statement $P_5$ does not.

So there can be no proof of $P_5$ using *only* $P_1,P_3.$

Comment: You beat me for 1 min!

Comment: I supposed it. Here is the article http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2308975?uid=3738664&uid=373515141&uid=2&uid=3&uid=60&sid=211025860884

Comment: @JoseAntonio I myself don't have access to the jstor article, and it only displayed the first page, without the part you deal with. I'd appreciate it if you could include a screen shot of the first few pages, enough to get through the statements you quoted about deriving $P_5$. Thanks.

Comment: @coffeemath: Ready, I edited and putted the point of the question. The other pages basically just extend what is means to be a Peano model and an Inductive model.

Comment: @JoseAntonio My bet is there's a typo and he meant to say "proof of $P_5$ requires all three axioms." [can't get the base case without axiom $P_1$] It also depends on what an "induction model" is defined to be, my guess there is an initial term and each term has a successor, and anything true of initial term and also if true for given term also true for successor is always true. This would make the examples like those given in the two answers here into "induction models".

Comment: @cofeemath: The author says: "It will be useful to introduce the term induction model to refer to any model which satisfies this axiom [Axiom P3] (...)". Thanks, also I think there is a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I think you do need (P2) as well for proving (P5).

Consider the set $N=\{ 0,1\}$ with "operation" 
$S$ defined by $S0=1=S1$. Then (P1) and (P3) hold, but (P5) does not.

Comment: Very clear. So maybe I misunderstood what the author wants to say. I need to read it again.